# EF concurrency - rowversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

What is this error, when I use the `RowVersion` field decorated with a `[timestamp]` attribute in Entity Framework code-first?

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

thanks.